# Problem pagination for category posts in Django

Tags: django, pagination

I used the following code for pagination and got the error I left here. please help.
Note that for categories whose number of posts is less than 2 (_paginator), there is no problem, but the same posts are more than two and pagination is done.

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . views import home, detail_article, category_list

app_name = "blog"
urlpatterns = [
       path('', home, name="home"),
       path('page/<int:page>', home, name="home"),
       path('post/<slug:slug>', detail_article, name="detail_article"),
       path('category/<slug:slug>', category_list, name="category_list"),
       path('category/<slug:slug>/page/<int:page>', category_list, name="category_list")
]
```

views.py:

```
def category_list(request, slug, page=1):
category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug, status=True)
article_list = category.articles.published()
_paginator = Paginator(article_list, 2)
articles = _paginator.get_page(page)
context = {
    'category':category,
    'articles':articles
}
return render(request, 'blog/category.html', context)
```

template.html:

```
<!-- Paginator -->
                    {% if articles.has_other_pages %}
                    <div class="col-12 pagging">
                        <ul>
                            {% if articles.has_previous %}
                            <li>
                                <a href="{% url 'blog:category_list' category.slug articles.previous_page_number %}">
                                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            {% else %}
                            <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-right a-active" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                            {% endif %} 
                            <!-- {% for i in articles.paginator.page_range %} {% if articles.number == i %}
                            <li><span class="a-active">{{ i }}</span></li>
                            {% else %}
                            <li><a href="{% url 'blog:category'  %} page/{{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                            {% endif %} {% endfor %}  -->
                            {% if articles.has_next %}
                            <li>
                                <a href="{% url 'blog:category_list' category.slug articles.next_page_number %}">
                                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            {% else %}
                            <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-left a-active" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                            {% endif %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    <!-- end paginator -->
```

and error! :(
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sB7YM.png)

Comment: The HTML in *comment* is still rendered by the template engine.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML in *comment* is still rendered by the template engine. So you should remove the `{% url 'blog:category' %}` parts. If you want to put comment in a Django template, you do that between `{# … #}`, or you can use a [**`{% comment %} … {% endcomment %}`** template block [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#comment).

For example:

```
{% if articles.has_previous %}
<li>
    <a href="{% url 'blog:category_list' category.slug articles.previous_page_number %}">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</li>
{% else %}
<li><i class="fa fa-arrow-right a-active" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
{% endif %}

{% comment %}
<!-- {% for i in articles.paginator.page_range %} {% if articles.number == i %}
<li><span class="a-active">{{ i }}</span></li>
{% else %}
<li><a href="{% url 'blog:category'  %} page/{{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
{% endif %} {% endfor %}  -->
{% endcomment %}

{% if articles.has_next %}
<li>
    <a href="{% url 'blog:category_list' category.slug articles.next_page_number %}">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
</li>
{% else %}
<li><i class="fa fa-arrow-left a-active" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: tanks. i remove {% url 'blog:category' %} parts, but there is still this problem !

Comment: @Remo: well likely another problem :) or at least on another location (that was not included).

Answer (score 0):

fixed problem! :)

```
                               {% for i in articles.paginator.page_range %} 
                           {% if articles.number == i %}
                            <li><span class="a-active">{{ i }}</span></li>
                            {% else %}
                            <li><a href="{% url 'blog:home'   %}category/{{category.slug}}/page/{{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                            {% endif %} {% endfor %}
```